# How to document PUT through "hidden" POST field

Tags: http, swagger, documentation, openapi, swagger-ui

I'm trying to use swagger to document an API but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to document a PUT/DELETE method that works by using POST with a so called hidden `_method` parameter that indicates the type of request.

Example:

This is a POST request

```
POST /v1/index HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost

data=1
```

This is a PUT request

```
POST /v1/index HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost

_method=PUT&data=1
```

How can I document this using OpenAPI/Swagger?

Comment: It looks like you're sending it as form data in the body, so: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/. Or if you mean how can you make it appear as an actual PUT: you can't, because it isn't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe well that's how PUT used to be implemented, and probably still is in APIs that need to support browsers. But I can't also add two separate POST methods, so my only option is to document two operations as one and add details in the description? This would be quite ugly when both operations require different parameters..

Comment: From OpenAPI's perspective, because it's the same method, it's all one operation with multiple behaviours. Yes that's awkward to document, because it's non-standard. And it's not about needing to support browsers, any client should be able to make requests with any method, not jam them all into POSTs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I believe this is due to PHP backends that don't parse body parameters unless it's a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by modifying swagger initializer, adding a request interceptor:

```
requestInterceptor: function (req) {
  var method = (req.method || "GET").toLowerCase();
  if (method !== "get" && method !== "post) {
    if (req.body) {
      req.body += "&";
    }
    req.body += "_method=" + req.method;
    req.method = "POST";
  }
  
  return req;
},
```